Contentful migration - Reference field - how to enable selecting from existing entries only?
I'm writing a migration script to add a field which accepts references to other entries.
I'd like to be able to set the Show "Create new entries" values (see screenshot) to No in the script, but I can't find anything in the Contentful docs that describes this property.
Does anyone know?

